# How do I make an instance of a new object run its methods upon creation?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype, this

Hello I am having an issue with self invoking a function that belongs to an object's prototype. My goal is to create a method for a custom object that invokes a function it has upon creating an instance.

```js
function Message(text) {
  this.text = text;
}

Message.prototype.send = function() {
  alert(this.text);
}();

var testMessage = new Message("Hello Goodbye");
```

The issue here is I receive undefined when I create an instance of the Message object. It may have to do with the way the keyword, "this" is defined as, although I am not completely sure. However if instead of adding the method to the prototype and just put it in the function, it works fine like the one below.

```js
function Message(text) {
  this.text = text;
  this.send = function() {
    alert(text);
  }();
}

var testMessage = new Message("Hello Goodbye");
```

Comment: Because in first example `this` is not referring to `Message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The send method runs exactly when you invoke it with `()` - examine your control flow.

In your first case, you define a function on Message's prototype attribute, then invoke it. It alerts undefined, because Message.prototype (`this` in that context) does not contain a text attribute.

In your second case you add `text` to `this` before invoking `send`, thus making it defined when the alert runs.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I removed the braces and will just call the method normally. My intention was to have that method run when an instance of the Message object was created.